# Зачем решарпер предлагает создать новый IEnumerable<INode>?

Tags: c#, массивы, list, anglesharp

Имеется `IEnumerable<INode>` который получаем с помощью `LINQ`, далее работаем с ним, но решарпер зачем-то предлагает сделать каст к `INode[]` и пересоздать `IEnumerable<INode>`. Говоря при этом:

> Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable
>
> Возможно многократное перечисление интерфейс ienumerable

В чем подвох?

```
public async Task<PaginationModel> LoadPaginationData()
{
    IEnumerable<INode> nodes = _dleContent.QuerySelectorAll(".navi").First().QuerySelector("span.navigation")
        .ChildNodes.Where(node => node.NodeType != NodeType.Text);

    IEnumerable<INode> enumerable = nodes as INode[] ?? nodes.ToArray();

    int currentPage = int.Parse(enumerable
        .First(node => node.NodeName.Equals("SPAN") && !node.TextContent.Trim().Equals("..."))
        .TextContent);

    PaginationModel result = new PaginationModel
    {
        UpdateTime = DateTime.Now,
        PaginationData = enumerable.ToDictionary(
            node => node.TextContent.Trim().Equals("...") ? -1 : int.Parse(node.TextContent),
            node => new Uri("http://example.com/")),
        CurrentPageId = currentPage
    };

    return await Task.FromResult(result);
}
```

Comment: "решарпер зачем-то предлагает сделать"- пусть предлагает. Resharper, как и другие подобные утилиты, дают "советы" исходя из тех алгоритмов, которые в него заложены. Только эти "советы" не всегда оправданы.

Comment: В конце концов разработчик - Вы. И решения должны принимать Вы, а не Resharper.

Comment: Чтобы избежать двойной материализации перечисления.

Comment: @tym32167: А это не потянет за собой утечек памяти, ведь ссылка на первое перечисление никуда не девается?

Comment: Никаких утечек памяти тут не будет

Comment: @tym32167: Это все ради этого? [Промежуточная материализация C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/intermediate-materialization)

Comment: В самой первой строчке добавьте ToArray() в конец nodes = _dlecontent....ToArray() и решарпер умолкнет

Comment: С телефона не удобно читать, но заголовок релевантный

Comment: @tym32167: Аааа, т.е. при каждом обращении, он будет заново обращаться к `_dleContent` и запрашивать новый список?

Comment: Да, добавил ответом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поглядим на вашу функцию до внесения изменений решарпером

```
public async Task<PaginationModel> LoadPaginationData()
{
    IEnumerable<INode> nodes = _dleContent.QuerySelectorAll(".navi").First().QuerySelector("span.navigation")
        .ChildNodes.Where(node => node.NodeType != NodeType.Text);  

    int currentPage = int.Parse(nodes
        .First(node => node.NodeName.Equals("SPAN") && !node.TextContent.Trim().Equals("..."))
        .TextContent);

    PaginationModel result = new PaginationModel
    {
        UpdateTime = DateTime.Now,
        PaginationData = nodes.ToDictionary(
            node => node.TextContent.Trim().Equals("...") ? -1 : int.Parse(node.TextContent),
            node => new Uri("http://example.com/")),
        CurrentPageId = currentPage
    };

    return await Task.FromResult(result);
}
```

Тут вы видите, что к переменной nodes идет обращение 2 раза. И в оба этих раза, так как переменная nodes - нематериализованное перечисление, перечисление будет материализоваться. То есть поиск по `_dleContent` в коде произойдет дважды.

А вот код, что предлагает решарпер

```
public async Task<PaginationModel> LoadPaginationData()
{
    IEnumerable<INode> nodes = _dleContent.QuerySelectorAll(".navi").First().QuerySelector("span.navigation")
        .ChildNodes.Where(node => node.NodeType != NodeType.Text);

    IEnumerable<INode> enumerable = nodes as INode[] ?? nodes.ToArray();

    int currentPage = int.Parse(enumerable
        .First(node => node.NodeName.Equals("SPAN") && !node.TextContent.Trim().Equals("..."))
        .TextContent);

    PaginationModel result = new PaginationModel
    {
        UpdateTime = DateTime.Now,
        PaginationData = enumerable.ToDictionary(
            node => node.TextContent.Trim().Equals("...") ? -1 : int.Parse(node.TextContent),
            node => new Uri("http://example.com/")),
        CurrentPageId = currentPage
    };

    return await Task.FromResult(result);
}
```

Как видно, обращение к нематериализованному перечислению идет только 1 раз, и после материализованный результат сохраняется в переменную `enumerable`, которая и используется в дальнейшем. То есть поиск по `_dleContent` произойдет только 1 раз, результаты поиска запомнятся в `enumerable` и переиспользуются.

ПО сути, вместо доп переменной вы могли бы просто материализовать перечисление сразу, например

```
    IEnumerable<INode> nodes = _dleContent.QuerySelectorAll(".navi").First().QuerySelector("span.navigation")
        .ChildNodes.Where(node => node.NodeType != NodeType.Text).ToArray();
```

Как пример для понимания, запустите следующий код и поглядите на вывод

```
var nodes = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(x => {Console.WriteLine(x); return x;});

var one = nodes.Where(x=>x%10==0).ToDictionary(x=>x,x=>x);
var two = nodes.Where(x=>x%10==0).First();
```

Тут мы создаем 1 перечисление и 2 раза его материализуем. То есть элементы перечисления будут выведены в консоль дважды.

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: Спасибо, сколько пользовался перечислениями, никогда о таком не догадывался.